# possible to recreate a file using metadata, SHA, and a few bytes?

Tags: compression, sha, lossless-compression

I may be a fool, but I hope that it would be possible to recreate an exact copy of a file if we only have:

- it's exact lenght and type
- a few of it's begining bytes( suppose 100)
- it's md5 and sha256 signatures.

I do not know if this possible, but so far I haven't been able to find online anything ressembling what I'm describing.

Sidenote: I know such process would be computationally expensive, so if possible I intend to try it with small files(1-3mb)

Comment: "small files", sorry, but you're on the wrong scale. With todays computers I would imagine you might be able to produce a file with the right sha if you're in the "tens of bytes" at most. Unless you have knowledge about how to target and break the digest algorithm being used your best attempt would be a simple brute force, and just iterating through all the possible byte combinations of, say, 128 bytes, given that you can calculate a billion billion billion digests (1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000) every second you're still looking at a runtime of over 10.000 years.

Comment: So I would say the safe answer to your question is that no, this is not practically possible.

Comment: Hah, sorry, did I say 10.000 years? That was for 128 **bits**. 128 **bytes** is like something something with 273 zeroes behind it **years**.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for taking your time and and anwsering my question, as stated earlier I knew it wasn't fast, but now thanks to you I now have an idea of wrong I was. Thank you for sharing your knowledge with me

Comment: I'm new here. How do i give the green checkmark?

Comment: If you want to learn more about this particular topic, you might want to google for "rainbow tables". Consider passwords which has been hashed by MD5, without a salt. Every user that typed in their password as "Passw0rd1234" will end up having the same MD5 value in the authentication database. A rainbow table is basically a **giant** lokup table of all MD5 values for passwords up to a certain length. A table for MD5 up to 12 characters is 1TB in size.

Comment: You actually don't, because I only used the commenting system. I can leave an actual answer, however, but it will be a negative answer (aka "can't be done"). You can only accept answers. Comments are just that, comments.

Comment: I left an answer instead of just a comment. You can accept that if you want. I imagine you actually asked a X/Y problem, however, and you have some form of digest identifying a file you lost. Unfortunately, neither of us will live long enough to find the real file (unless you have backup, *backup is king!*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not practical, and given your example of "small files (1-3mb)", you're way off in scale of what current computers will be able to do in terms of performance.

A simple [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28256%5E128%2F10%5E27%29%2F60%2F60%2F24%2F365) query to calculate how long

- 128 bytes of data file (256^128 possible combinations of byte sequences)
- when you can calculate a billion billion billion (10^9 * 10^9 * 10^9 = 10^27) digests every second
- ... in minutes, then hours, then days, then years

would take, and you end up with....

> 10463951242053391806136963369726580181263718864311851635192874886429209483641954321222640418122029864527291727710479949464718215680589004332016189037791576956967351342601788071700268169006221818240189631008834448226154239518944108944497601509840881752510934060240763835605888507473266002770708660224/1835636794567108154296875 years

or  *shortened* to ...

> 5.7004475357125694689539104223396268823502567825415606695024 × 10^273

aka "something something" with 273 zeroes at the end ... **years**.

Even taking in luck and average number of attempts before hitting the right number and you're to half of that, which is still... unfortunately several orders of magnitude larger than the expected heat death of our universe.

You will need a targetted attack on the digest algorithm you chose, exploiting known weaknesses. [SHA-1 has been "broken"](https://shattered.io/) in terms of having targetted collisions being made, but most of the other SHA-x implementations are still safe, relatively speaking.

Now, I picked "billion billion billion" as a rather generous estimate of how many digests you can computer in a second. I have no fricking idea if this is accurate or not but the result with 273 zeroes should tell you that even if I was off by an order of magnitude *or ten*, you're still far from there.

According to [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/18193/44045) from 2012, current computers (back then) could compute 100 million hashes per second of SHA512. If we apply [Moore's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law) to this and just double the performance every 18 months which I believe was the norm, we could potentially calculate 100 million * 2^(6) [=64] hashes today, which is roughly 6.4 billion hashes per second. We're still a billion billion hashes away in speed magnitude to reach our target (which still has 273 zeroes behind it).

Comment: You are the best person, ever.

Comment: Given that the above computation would take something something with 273 zeroes **years**, ever is such a lonely number, so I seriously doubt that, but I'm glad I was able to give you an answer :) I *still* think you asked an [X/Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem#:~:text=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20a,them%20to%20resolve%20issue%20X.) question though and would love to know why you asked your question that way to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Even with all the magic computing power you can imagine, what you are asking for is impossible. If you take a 1 MB file and compute its MD5 and SHA256, you are left with 384 bits. I will ignore the first 100 bytes of the file, which you say you know. You are still left with over eight million bits. Subtracting the 384, you still have over eight million bits.

That means that there are approximately 2<sup>8x10<sup>6</sup></sup>, (~10<sup>2,400,000</sup>) *different* 1 MB files that all map to *exactly the same* MD5 and SHA256 signatures. Even you could compute all of them, there is no way to determine which of them was the original file.